# WPF Value Converter to replace error code with localized string

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, idataerrorinfo

I have a viewmodel implementing the IDataErrorInfo interface for validation, for an error it produces a string which is a key in the resource dictionary for a localized string describing the error. However when trying to apply the following style and template to the textbox I get the red border but no tooltip, however removing my converter and using the default one gives me the tooltip but obviously not the localized string.

Can you see what I am doing wrong and/or if there is a better way of doing this?

```
class MessageCodeToMessageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            string messageCode = (string)value;
            try
            {
                return (string)App.Current.Resources[messageCode];
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return messageCode;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return "";
    }
}

        <local:MessageCodeToMessageConverter x:Key="Converter"></local:MessageCodeToMessageConverter>
        <Style x:Key="TextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ErrorTemplate">
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                </Border>
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Could you show `XAML` code where is your `TextBox` and how you apply style and template to the textbox?

Comment: Are you sure that `ConvertBack` method is called and key in the resource dictionary is founded? Your xaml looks correct.

Comment: The problem was that the resource was defined in a merged xaml resource dictionary and not directly in the App.xaml so I fixed this by making my value converter inherit framework element and using the find resource method. Not sure how 'correct' this was but the multi value converter looks like another option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion if your resource key is defined in the App.xaml then it should work. But your resource key is probably in resource in some user control. `(string)App.Current.Resources[messageCode];` search only in the App.xaml resource.
Solution for you can be use multivalueconverter

```
class MessageCodeToMessageConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter,     System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    FrameworkElement targetObject = values[0] as FrameworkElement;
    if (targetObject == null)
    {
       return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
    if (value != null)
    {
        string messageCode = (string)values[1];
        try
        {
            return targetObject.FindResource(messageCode);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return messageCode;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public object ConvertBack(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    return "";
}
}
```

and

```
<Style x:Key="TextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
  <Style.Triggers>
<Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
  <Setter Property="ToolTip">
    <Setter.Value>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                <Binding RelativeSource="{x:Static RelativeSource.Self}" Path="(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent" />
            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```